# Wordpress site menu issue on IE 7 browser

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, internet-explorer, css

i am creating wordpress site in this site menu work in all browser except ie 7 ,the problem was whenever Parent menu over the child menu display horizontally and z-index problem also

my site url

http://kitchco-dev.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you keep this changes only then work correctly

```
        nav li {
          position: relative;
          z-index: 99; 
            }

        #access li li
        {
        clear:both;
        display:block;
        }
```